# How to exclude a package from a transitive dependency of external jar included in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have included the following dependency in my build.gradle:

```
testCompile group: 'com.xebialabs.restito', name: 'restito', version:'0.5.1'
```

But with this jar other dependencies like *jersey-core-1.18.3.jar* also get included.

Now I want this jersey jar but this also has a package *javax.ws.rs.core* which contains classes that conflict with my latest version of javax.ws.rs.core included explicitly in build.gradle.

Is there any way that I can exclude only a specific package from a transitive dependency and not the whole dependency. I am a newbie to gradle so please correct  me if any incorrect term was used.

When I run the following command:

```
gradlew dependencies --configuration testCompile
```

it gives me following dependency tree. Only the relevant part is shown here

```
testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.

+--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:3.0.3
|    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.0.3 (*)
|    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
|    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
|    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.3 (*)
+--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-service-description:3.0.0-milestone1
|    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:3.0.0-milestone1 -> 3.0.3 (*)
+--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:1.9.13
|    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
|    \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13
|         \--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
+--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.12 -> 1.9.13 (*)
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1.2
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1.1
\--- com.xebialabs.restito:restito:0.5.1
     +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 -> 1.7.7
     +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.17
     |    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
     |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1
     +--- org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.4
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1 -> 1.7.7
     +--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-server:2.3.17
     |    \--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:2.3.17
     |         \--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:2.3.17
     +--- junit:junit:4.12
     |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-grizzly2:1.18.3
          +--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:2.2.16 -> 2.3.17 (*)
          +--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-server:2.2.16 -> 2.3.17 (*)
          \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.18.3
               \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.3

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Now the class *`Response`* in *`javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1`* is under the package *`javax.ws.rs.core`*. Similarly there is another *`Response`* class present in *`com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.3`* in package *`javax.ws.rs.core`*. But the later one contains earlier version which does not has *`readEntity()`* method introduced in rs-api 2.0. The dependency for *`Response`* in my project gets resolved to the earlier version always.

Answer (score 14):

Citing gradle user guide section about [Excluding transitive dependencies](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies):

> You can exclude a transitive dependency either by configuration or by dependency:
>
> **Example 50.14**
>
> ```
> configurations {
>     compile.exclude module: 'commons'
>     all*.exclude group: 'org.gradle.test.excludes', module: 'reports'
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile("org.gradle.test.excludes:api:1.0") {
>     exclude module: 'shared'
>     }
> }
> ```

So back to your case, you can simply just take one of the methods described above and replace the modules in the example with with the module you'd like to exclude, e.g.

```
configurations {
    testCompile.exclude group: 'javax.ws.rs', module: 'jsr311-api'
}
```

---

**Update** (per the additional details provided)

What you have to do is to add to your script the following lines

```
configurations {
  testCompile.exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jersey-core'
}
```

Consider the following minimal `build.gradle` script:

apply plugin: 'java'

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
  // Excluding com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.3, option #1: 
  // compile.exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jersey-core'
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:3.0.3"
    compile ("com.sun.jersey:jersey-grizzly2:1.18.3") {
      // Excluding com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.3, option #2: 
      // exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jersey-core'
    }
}
```

Now, with the file above as is running `gradlew dependencies --configuration testCompile` you'll get the next dependency tree:

```
+--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:3.0.3
|    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.0.3
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1
|    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4
|    |    \--- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:2.1.0
|    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
|    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
|    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.3
|         \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.0.3 (*)
\--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-grizzly2:1.18.3
     +--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:2.2.16
     |    \--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:2.2.16
     +--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-server:2.2.16
     |    +--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:2.2.16 (*)
     |    \--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-rcm:2.2.16
     |         \--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:2.2.16
     \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.18.3
          \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.3
```

Note that `com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.18.3` is listed as a transitive dependency. Now, uncommenting either of the exclusion options and rerunning the same command you'll get the following output which does contain this module:

```
+--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:3.0.3
|    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.0.3
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1
|    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4
|    |    \--- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:2.1.0
|    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
|    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
|    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.3
|         \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.0.3 (*)
\--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-grizzly2:1.18.3
     +--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:2.2.16
     |    \--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:2.2.16
     +--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-server:2.2.16
     |    +--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:2.2.16 (*)
     |    \--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-rcm:2.2.16
     |         \--- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:2.2.16
     \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.18.3
```

Comment: Thanks @Amnon. I tried the similar solution but didn't work. In my problem the jersey core has an internal package structure of javax.ws.rs.core and similarly RS- api2.0 has the same structure. javax.ws.rs.core. I want my Response to take later one.

Comment: Looking at the pom files in MavenCentral I'm not sure that I spotted the exact jars you'd like to exclude. Can you please add to your question the dependencies tree? For the testCompile configuration you can simply run `gradlew dependencies --configuration testCompile`, paste the output of it and mark the artifact you'd to skip downloading.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. Thanks