# How to exclude module/package dependency org.w3c.dom from jOpenDocument with Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a modular project that requires `jOpenDocument` library. The problem is that `jOpenDocument` comes with `org.w3c.dom`, which conflicts with the same dependency introduced by `java.xml`, so I get the following errors:

```
error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and java.xml
error: module javafx.graphicsEmpty reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and java.xml
error: module javafx.baseEmpty reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and java.xml
error: module jOpenDocument reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and java.xml
error: module javafx.controlsEmpty reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and java.xml
error: module org.xerial.sqlitejdbc reads package org.w3c.dom from both java.xml and jOpenDocument
```

I tried to exclude the dependency from `jOpenDocument`, there is a number of useful links for that:
[Exclude Package From Gradle Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942825/exclude-package-from-gradle-dependency),
https://tomgregory.com/how-to-exclude-gradle-dependencies/ and [How to exclude a package from a transitive dependency of external jar included in build.gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237435/how-to-exclude-a-package-from-a-transitive-dependency-of-external-jar-included-i) but no success. I can imagine there is a state of the art solution for that but I cannot see it. Can anyone point to some direction?

Here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.9'
    id "org.beryx.jlink" version "2.25.0"
    id 'eclipse'
}

sourceCompatibility = "11"
targetCompatibility = "11"

javafx {    
    version = 14
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls','javafx.fxml']
}

application {
    mainModule = "Pervap3" 
    mainClass = "application.Main"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    
    implementation 'org.glassfish:jakarta.json:2.0.1'
    
    implementation('org.jopendocument:jOpenDocument:1.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.w3c.dom'
    }
    
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.39.3.0'    
}
```

For completeness, I am working in Eclipse 2022-06 which does not seem to integrate so well with Gradle. After some struggle I found that the `eclipse plugin` is required for a total merge of Gradle and Eclipse. Introducing that I managed to obtain the "Project and External Dependencies" item in the eclipse project explorer, which previously was not appearing. Now the project tree looks better, the dependencies managed by Gradle are now listed, but Eclipse still issues the "Type not accessible" error in my Java code and I am not sure why.

Comment: I have the same problem. My investigations are settling on this being an Implementation Conflict where there are two "capabilities" at the the same version that are able to satisfy the w3c dependency. Gradle provides a cure.  I just have work out if there is an out of the box fix or if I have to craft something in DSL for the ResolutionStrategy. I am new to both. Have you tried a build scan?

Comment: I solved my problem by dropping `jOpenDocument` and adopting `odfdom`. I am quite happy with my choice. Odfdom worked out of the box in my modular project by adding the dependency to the Gradle build system. I have been suggested in the jOpenDocument discussion group to include the library as source code, but I could not make it work. The time I spent to refactor the existing code to use odfdom was much less that trying to fix jOpenDocument (without success).

Comment: Congrats. I am getting the problem with both jOpenDocument and odfdom.  I now think it is a module problem or a byproduct of the other version upgrades that Gradle applied elsewhere in the build.

Comment: I suggest to also double check you run configurations. I work in Intellij and for some reason I do not recall my run configuration caused problems. After fixing that, odfdom worked out of the box. This is the dependency I used: `implementation 'org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:0.11.0'`

Comment: Odfdom is not yet modularized. There is an issue on this. My build uses a plug-in that reassembles the classpath packages into a module for use with jlink. So, I have 2 modules exporting the same w3c package. Java does not allow this & now enforces this rule. I haven't yet worked out how to exercise package level control in Gradle configurations. I don't know enough to say whether a solution exists. I think I'll put this on the back burner awaiting inspiration.

Comment: Before I do I will try your suggestion about excluding org.w3c.dom from odftoolkit / jOpendocument. I should have done this a while ago, but I wanted to understand what this was doing. And so I dived down the rabbit hole.